# selenium-java-2.43.0 does not work with firefox 36

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I had installed "selenium-java-2.43.0" and all my testfiles executed ok using firefox 33 but when firefox updated to firefox 36 the web browser could not load the page.
Do I have to update to selenium-java-2.4x.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are *incompatibility issues*:

- [Firefox 36 breaks WebDriver 2.44.0](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8399)
- [Selenium 2.44.0 unable to connect Firefox 36](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8525)

You need you **upgrade selenium** to `2.45` (currently latest).

---

Or, alternatively, *downgrade Firefox* to 34.0.5 (35 is also not an option).

Comment: Another thing to add though, there is a serious performance degradation with `2.45`. See [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8551). So, rolling back to 34 is probably better idea

Comment: Accepting the answer was regarding to go back to firefox 33. Now I did update using selenium-2.45.0.tar.gz (having also firefox updated to 36.0), but execution fails since profile not found. Any solution for that?

Comment: @SharosMass could you elaborate and show how you initialize the driver with a profile? Thanks.

Comment: def setUp(self):
  self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  self.driver.get("https://secure4-qa.volvo.com/vcgdotaportal")

Comment: As far as I can tell, Selenium 2.45 (fetched from the repo via Maven) is still broken under Firefox 36 (specifically, 36.0.4 Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0) as of now (3/24/15). It was previously working with the version of Firefox installed by Xubuntu 14.04 (probably 35, but non-inconceivably 34 or an earlier release of 36).

Comment: I did the steps that @alexce recommended but the I got the error  **Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'** . I am using ff 36 and selenium 2.45.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.. The latest ff version does not support selenium 2.43..you need to downgrade your ff version

Also you can try with other browsers for that you need to have driver for that browser say fo ex chrome driver.