# Splinter, opens up browser but won't visit webpage

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, splinter

```
from splinter import Browser 
browser = Browser()
browser.visit('http://www.google.com/')
```

Straight from their tutorial, and all it does is open up a window, and I do not recieve any errors. I've reinstalled several times, and if it opens up a browser window and I receive no errors, it's obviously installed correctly, so why is this happening?

Comment: Since this is simply a troubleshooting question for splinter, it belongs either on the [splinter issues list](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/issues) or on SO.

Comment: Selenium seems to work, so I'm just gonna go with that instead.

Comment: What browser, what version and what `splinter` version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

There are incompatibility issues between certain `selenium` (that `splinter` uses under-the-hood) and `Firefox` versions, see related threads:

- [selenium-java-2.43.0 does not work with firefox 36](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905808/selenium-java-2-43-0-does-not-work-with-firefox-36)
- [Using Firefox 35 with protractor results into an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645260/using-firefox-35-with-protractor-results-into-an-error)

There are other options, but you can solve it by upgrading selenium (2.45 is currently latest):

```
pip install --upgrade selenium
```

and installing `Firefox` 36 (currently latest).

Comment: Ok... so I restarted my computer... Selenium was already up to date.. so I ran the script without changing anything, and it worked? Not sure what happened... but thanks anyway :)